# InstallShiled2011+Install Folder Getting Deleted

Tags: installshield

I have an application, which is getting installed C:\ProgramFiles\RootFolder\InstallDir.

I have another application which is also getting installed in same root folder , eg:
C:\ProgramFiles\RootFolder\InstallDirofAnotherApp.

Here when I am trying to reinstall my application, it is deleting the entire Root Folder, It doesn't mind about the another installation of the other one.

So, it is deleting  C:\ProgramFiles\RootFolder

Is there any setting to do like that? This is a legacy project and I am new to this. Unable to fine the cause

Thanks,
Nanda

Answer (score 0):

What type of projects are these applications (basic MSI, or InstallScript)? Check [INSTALLDIR] (General Information -> INSTALLDIR) in both packages; if these properties are different, see if there is any custom action that perhaps delete some files/directories.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. Yes, There is a custom action related to this. I am checking on that.